# Adding together string-based minutes and seconds values

Tags: ruby, string, time, integer, converters

I have a a `Track` model that has a duration attribute. The attribute is string based, and reads in `minutes:seconds` format. I was wondering what the best way would be to take these string-based values and add them together. For example, if there are duration values like this:

```
Duration 1: "1:00"
Duration 2: "1:30"
```

how could I get it to output `"2:30"`?

Most of the questions I found related to this issue start with an integer based value. What's the best way to get this done?

Comment: Your question could be improved in a couple of ways: 1) It should illustrate the needed carry-over from seconds to minutes (e.g., add `Duration 3: "2:50"` and say you are looking for an output of `"5:20"`; 2) Your example should be complete with actual Ruby objects, (e.g., `arr = { :Duration_1 => "1:00", :Duration_2 => "1:30", :Duration_3 => "2:50" }`), thereby allowing readers to cut and paste. Notice that I've defined a variable (`arr`) equal to the hash. That way, readers can refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way this can be done:

```
class Track
    attr_accessor :duration

    def initialize(duration)
        @duration = duration
    end
end

arr = [Track.new("1:00"), Track.new("1:30")]

total_seconds = arr.reduce(0) do |a, i| 
    min, sec = i.duration.split(":").map(&:to_i)
    a + min * 60 + sec
end

p total_duration = '%d:%02d' % total_seconds.divmod(60)
#=> "2:30"
```

Comment: Since you are using `reduce`, you don't need to do `a +=`. The last line in the loop should be simplified to `a + min * 60 + sec`.

Comment: `[total_seconds / 60, total_seconds % 60]` is equivalent to `total_seconds.divmod(60)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Fixed it now

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to store/manipulate them as seconds.

It's definitely easier to store them as the integer number of seconds, and apply a function to parse/format the value into the proper string representation.

Storing them as integer will make it very easy to sum and subtract them.

Comment: Whatever type you assign to the attribute wouldn't there still need to be some sort've conversion done to get the desired result? In a sense Wand Maker's answer adds and could potentially subtract the values could it not?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I missed @Wand's earlier answer, which is the same as mine. I'll leave mine just for the way I've organized the calculations.

```
arr = %w| 1:30 3:07 12:53 |
  #=> ["1:30", "3:07", "12:53"] 

"%d:%2d" % arr.reduce(0) do |tot,str|
  m,s = str.split(':')
  tot + 60*m.to_i + s.to_i
end.divmod(60)
  #=> "17:30"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to implement something like this in a recent project. Here is a simple start. If you are sure you will always have this format 'H:S', you will not need to convert your duration to time objects:

```
entries = ["01:00", "1:30", "1:45"]

hours = 0
minutes = 0

entries.each do |e|
  entry_hours, entry_minutes = e.split(':', 2)
  hours += entry_hours.to_i
  minutes += entry_minutes.to_i
end
hours += (minutes/60)
minutes = (minutes%60)
p "#{hours}:#{minutes}"
#=> "4:15"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SimoneCarletti: store them as an integer number of seconds.  However, you could wrap them in a duration value class that can output itself as a nicely formatted string.

```
class Duration
  attr_accessor :seconds

  def initialize(string)
    minutes, seconds = string.split(':', 2)
    @seconds = minutes.to_i * 60 + seconds.to_i
  end

  def to_s
    sprintf("%d:%02d", @seconds / 60, @seconds % 60)
  end

  def self.sum(*durations)
    Duration.new(durations.reduce(0) { |t,d| t + d.seconds })
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: Added a sum method similar to that suggested by @CarySwoveland below.  You can use this as follows:

```
durations = ["1:30", "2:15"].map { |str| Duration.new(str) }
total = Duration.sum *durations
```

Comment: You might consider adding a class method to sum times: `def self.sum(*durations); "%d:%02d" % durations.reduce(0) { |t,d| t + d.seconds }.divmod(60); end`. This could be used as follows: `durations = ["1:30", "2:45"].map { |str| Duration.new(str) } #=> [#<Duration:0x007fab8c026c48 @seconds=90>, #<Duration:0x007fab8c026b80 @seconds=165>]`, followed by `Duration.sum *durations #=> "4:15"`.